# Chrooting a ftp user to a particular directory

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, chroot

I would like to chroot a user to their home directory on a debian linux server. Im using vsftpd server.

I've done it with a user before, and now cant remember how to do it. I've limited ssh access to the root user so the chrooted user cant ssh.

Anyone think of what i may be missing?

--Mark

Comment: here is the two users from /etc/passwd

chrooted: 
joomla:x:1001:100::/www/site1/docs:/bin/sh

not chrooted
wordpress:x:1003:100::/www/site2/docs:/bin/sh

Comment: As an added level of security you should never allow root ssh directly, always ssh in as a regular user and su to root

Comment: Im aware of the risk im taking, and im sure there a lot of things I can do to beef up my security, short of plugging it off the LAN. Would really appreciate an answer to my question though.

Answer (score 2):

Add

`chroot_local_user=YES`

to vsftpd.conf.

Comment: I have that setting set. I have one ftp user already up there that is chrooted fine. Tried adding another system user and its not chrooted.

Comment: Attach the lines for the chrooted user and for the new user from /etc/passwd to your question.

Comment: Done. See above.