# FTP for Clients

Tags: ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does FTP Jailing mean, and what features does a server OS require in order to enable it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24706/what-does-ftp-jailing-mean-and-what-features-does-a-server-os-require-in-order-t)

Hi ,

If I wanted to grant my Clients Access to my server via FTP is a there a way they can only gain access to a certain folder like a a drop box ?

If so could you please advice me on the steps I would need to take or an article explaining this method.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These other questions on ftp jails should answer your question:

- [What does FTP Jailing mean, and what features does a server OS require in order to enable it?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24706/what-does-ftp-jailing-mean-and-what-features-does-a-server-os-require-in-order-t)
- [Chrooting a ftp user to a particular directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/50293/chroot-ftp-user)

Answer (score 0):

It depends massively on your ftp server, but most servers can be configured to show only a small fraction of the filesystem. Whether you can do that on a per-user basis is up to your FTP server software.

Comment: If you was going to do it which would be the best possible solution or do you not know......